# Join or filter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given 100 000 record table which of those 2 would be faster search?

```
create table #SearchSet(Item varchar(10))
insert into @SearchSet(Item)
values(('AA'),('BB'),('CC'),('DD22'),('AC123'),('456AA'),('125AA15'),('A154A'),('DDSSAA'),('55KKAA'))

select t1.*
from Table1 as t1
join #SearchSet as s
on t1.Column1 = s.Item

drop table #SearchSet
```

or this

```
select *
from Table1
where ColumnA = 'AA' or ColumnA = 'BB' or ColumnA = 'CC' or ColumnA = 'DD22' or ColumnA = 'AC123'
or ColumnA = '456AA' or ColumnA = '125AA15' or ColumnA = 'A154A' or ColumnA = 'DDSSAA' or `ColumnA = '55KKAA'`
```

Comment: when you tested it what were your results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to really answer a performance question is to test the different versions in your environment.

You have so few values for the comparison (just 10), that I would expect the `where` clause to work better.  Plus as your query is written, it cannot take advantage of an index, which could really help the first version.

If you add an index, then the first might be competitive with the second.  Try doing this:

```
create table #SearchSet(Item varchar(10) primary key);
insert into @SearchSet(Item)
    values(('AA'),('BB'),('CC'),('DD22'),('AC123'),('456AA'),('125AA15'),('A154A'),('DDSSAA'),('55KKAA'));
```

If you were comparing hundreds or thousands of values, I would expect the temporary table with a primary key to be faster.

Comment: you actually answered between the lines... This is just a conceptual sample. My application will involve several search sets derived from small filtered tables containing options. Those options will have unique ids as primary keys and those ids will be referenced in the table that will be searched thus the join will be on indexed values. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

on a small list like this, likely not much difference.  On a bigger list the join should be faster if you

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_SearchSet ON #searchset (item)
```

Either way, the real winner is to:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table1 ON Table1 (ColumnA)
```

If you're using SQL2012 and the results are sparse, do:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table1 ON Table1 (ColumnA) WHERE ColumnA in ('val1', 'val2', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

First one will return data faster.Reason being in second case you will perform multiple visits to the table and the data page itself. 
Also Create a non-clustered Index on Table1. This will ensure data is retrieved faster